# C++ type-punning when reading Numpy array via Pybind11

Tags: c++, pointers, pybind11

**I was wondering if anyone knows if the below "type punning" is necessary or if a more efficient technique or approach is best in the last line?**

The data is an 2D Numpy array of doubles which is passed by reference as the function argument.

side point: If this function is called indefinetly will a memory leak/ error eventually occur as the ptr_sum pointer is being created each time the function is run on the same identical memory address / location, Im not deleting the pointer "ptr_sum" as it seems to delete the underlying data in the memory location it points to?

double* ptr_sum = (double*)buf_summary.ptr;

```
void Pricing::price_all(py::array_t<double>& in_summary){

if (in_summary.ndim() != 2) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Results should be a 2-D Numpy array");
}

py::buffer_info buf_summary = in_summary.request(); // summary

// Pointer definition
double* ptr_sum = (double*)buf_summary.ptr;
```

Comment: I'm no expert on Python or PyBind but I can see that the `.ptr` member of the `pr:buffer_info` structure is a `void*`. So the **cast** to a `double*` (it's not type punning, really) would seem about right. But don't do anything like deleting that buffer via your cast pointer ... presumably, the source (Python) module will take care of managing/releasing the memory.

Comment: Note that the `double* ptr_sum = (double*)buf_summary.ptr;` doesn't **do** anything to the pointed-to data; nor does it create anything. It just assigns the address in the py:: structure to your local pointer variable.

Comment: Tip: never `delete` what you have not `new`ed. And never `new` anything, as long as you can use library utilities to create and manage objects.

Comment: @Red.Wave thank you very much for your tip, when you mention utilities are you referring to smart pointers for automatic memory management etc? thank you

Comment: @AdrianMole Thank you for this very helpful information, may I please ask, is the memory used in "double* ptr_sum " to store the memory address of my Ndimensional array cleaned, after the scope of the function it is within changes / method Pricing::price_all() ends? or else every time I call "Pricing::price_all" the memory will get eaten up?

Comment: @Py_trader smart pointers are just a verbose set of tools; they are pointers. All the dynamic sized containers - STL or not - internally deal with memory allocation; But their API is clean.